# Magento2 Rest api checkout

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, magento2.2, rest-api

Get the response from rest API. after that how to place an order based on success or failure messages. If success then only place an order else show the failure message on the checkout page.

```
try {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            echo $response;
        }
```

Can you please any one help me.